# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cost_'

Tags: python, label, cluster-analysis, k-means, attributeerror

I am trying to conduct Kprototype clustering algorithm. When I both run the model and try to do the cost graph as follows, I always get a 'no attribute' error for labels_ and cost_ functions. I checked the examples on several web sites, but there is no difference. What can I do? Thank you for your help.

1)

```
from kmodes.kmodes import KModes

from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes

kproto1 = KPrototypes(n_clusters=15, init='Cao').fit_predict(data,categorical = [23])
labels= kproto1.labels_ 

**AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'label_'**
```

2. 

```
cost = []
range_cluster=[5,8,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,70,85,100]

for num_clusters in range_cluster:
    kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='Cao').fit_predict(data, categorical=[23])
    cost.append(kproto.cost_)

plt.plot(cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes/blob/3402a0dfef6cfc2d4a23ca191e5646dbaa51386a/kmodes/kprototypes.py#L211), there are 2 ways to achieve this :
fit_predict method will return a tuple of labels, cost. So to get your labels, you should :

```
kproto1_result = KPrototypes(n_clusters=15, init='Cao').fit_predict(data,categorical = [23]) 
labels= kproto1[0]
```

or the 2nd method is just using the fit method :

```
kproto1 = KPrototypes(n_clusters=15, init='Cao').fit(data,categorical = [23]) 
labels = kproto1.labels_
```

Comment: Thank you very much, using only 'fit' helped me to reach what I want.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you kindly put this thread as solved? :)